# $timeout guarantees when implementing a cache service in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am implementing my own cache because I need it to be aware of the semantics of my application. I am implementing the cache within a client API that access a REST service. The logic is simple: I first look into my own dictionary of objects, and if the requested object is not present, then I use the network to request the object from the REST service. The code using the client API will expect a promise, even if the requested object is in my cache. My question is: What is the best way of implementing a promise/deferred pattern for the objects in the cache? Right now I am using a timeout function to do that. Is the timeout function good enough:? What guarantees do I have that the timeout function will execute after the user of the API receives the promise object? To look into the details of my question, please, see the code below:

Simplifying code to show only what is relevant to the question:

```
angular.module("myApp").factory("restClient", function($q, $http, $timeout, cache){

    var get_content=function(link){
       var deferred=$q.defer();
       $http.get(link)
       .success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
            deferred=null;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
            deferred=null;
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

 return{

      getObject : function(objectId) {
          //If object is in the cache
          if (cache.contains(objectId)){

             var deferred=$q.defer();
             $timeout(function (){

                  var objectContent=cache.get(objectId);
                  deferred.resolve(objectContent);
                  deferred=null;

             });
             return deferred.promise;


          }
          else{

             //Create link
             //return promise
             return get_content(link);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Where are you putting into the cache?

Comment: I have to put into the cache right here too in the client, but I have skipped the details of that algorithm.

Comment: you had left a comment, which you retracted... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you are trying to do, one important thing is not to create a redundant deferred promise object when you already have objects that returns a promise, ex:- `$http` and `$timeout`. You could do:-

```
 var get_content=function(link){
      return $http.get(link)
       .then(function (response) {
            cache.put(link, response.data);
            return response.data;
        }, function(response){
            return $q.reject(response.data);
        });

    };

 return {

      getObject : function(objectId) {
          //If object is in the cache
          if (cache.contains(objectId)){
            return $q.when(cache.get(objectId))
          }
          return get_content(objectId);
       }
```

Or even better instead of placing the data in the cache you could put the promise itself onto the cache.

```
   getObject : function(objectId) {
     if (cache.contains(objectId)){
        return cache.get(objectId);
     }

     var promise = $http.get(objectId)
       .then(function (response) {
            //Incase you have any condition to look at the response and decide if this is a failure then invalidate it here form the cache.
            return response.data;
        }, function(response){
            cache.remove(objectId); //Remove it
            return $q.reject("Rejection reason");
        });
       }
      cache.put(objectId, promise);
     return promise;
```

Comment: @ASDF One question why can't u use http default caching, by setting cache:true for your get requests, only urls are different correct?

Comment: I could, but I oversimplified. My cache will be a smart cache in that, for example, if in my url I am requesting a list of elements, I will check if I have some of those elements in my cache, and then create a new url that requests a shorter list of elements with the missing elements. That's why I decided to implement my own cache.

Comment: Which makes it trickier to handle promises, but I've got some idea on how to extend that code.

Comment: Why the explicit `$q.reject`  in the failure handler?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for your edit, but one question related to moving the caching outside, if the first real request fails won't it cache the promise that will always fail? So subsequent request ultimately will all be failures, instead of grabbing the data by making the network call?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have rolled back your edit, since your edit was invalid.

Comment: @PSL it's perfectly fine for that to happen (if it failed once chances are a 404 is still a 404 and a 500 is still a 500), if you want to revert changes on a web hit failure - it's preferable to do that when the response comes (that is, add it to the cache and remove it in the fail handler.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum _if it failed once chances are a 404 is still a 404 and a 500 is still a 500_  You can't be sure of that (You are focusing on only the fact that same urls might get hit subsequently, but that is trivial based on OP's question, and purpose if that OP is caching it for later use). You application might have cached the promised (that was rejected) and you might be hitting the same url, say sometime later, When the service might have been running fine by now, yet you will get wrong results. But You could cache and you should atleast remove it when the service failure happens.

Comment: In that case remove it on service failure, otherwise you might be sending several requests here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum updated... I should have updated instead of rollback, but it was difficult to update it from mobile. Its 5th edit now.. :)